# Where do I find where woocommerce stores product data in cpanel file manager?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I updated my woocommerce and it destroyed my wordpress site today. I get a  Apparently I'm dumb and didn't setup my godaddy back ups properly. I get a "page isn't working" HTTP ERROR 500. Before I manually delete the woocommerce folder and go back and then reinstall it, I don't want to loose all of the copy for the products that I have which I've spent days writing with my team. Where do I go in file manager (cpanel) to get the product pages so I can at least save all the marketing copy?

Thanks! Sorry, total wordpress noob here.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. You might be best off seeking support from your host for some help.  The product "pages" are stored in your WordPress database as a custom post type.  Unless you've improperly customized the WooCommerce templates and left them in the plugin's folder instead of your theme, there should be nothing in the plugin folder you would lose.  But before you do *anything* - make sure you've backed up what you have at this point (both files and db).  All of that said, this isn't the right kind of question for WPSE - it's a support question you should seek out via your host or the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Your products content are storied in database. take a backup of your database from cpanel and may be configure it into a new subdomain or local server and test. 
also please don't forget to take a backup of wp-contents folder where you have uploded all products images and other data.

Thank you